# How to do compile-time recursion over a given set of template template classes?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae, stdtuple

**Aim:** To do compile-time recursion over a given set of [template template classes](https://blog.feabhas.com/2014/08/templates-of-templates/) to compute a given function.

**Problem:** I could not devise how the `template` arguments should look like for `run_tests` function.

**MWE:** Please consider the following code example **working** for a given set of **built-in types** (*This example is based on an answer in stackoverflow, which I couldn't find it back so far - I will add the link when I find it*):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class Type>
void test(Type)
{
    // Do nothing
    std::cout<< "I survived 2020" << std::endl;
}

// Do compile-time recursion over the given types
template<std::size_t I = 0, typename... Tp>
inline typename std::enable_if<I == sizeof...(Tp), void>::type
run_tests
(
    const std::tuple<Tp...>& types
)
{}

template<std::size_t I = 0, typename... Tp>
inline typename std::enable_if<I < sizeof...(Tp), void>::type
run_tests
(
    const std::tuple<Tp...>& types
)
{
    test(std::get<I>(types));

    run_tests<I + 1, Tp...>(types);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    const std::tuple<int, double> types    // working
    // const std::tuple                    // not working
    // <
    //     std::vector<std::vector<int>>,
    //     std::vector<std::vector<double>>
    // > types
    (
        std::make_tuple(nullptr, nullptr)
    );

    run_tests(types);

    return 0;
}
```

**Attempts:** I have commented out the commented piece of code above, i.e.:

```
// const std::tuple<int, double> types    // working
const std::tuple                          // not working
<
    std::vector<std::vector<int>>,
    std::vector<std::vector<double>>
> types
```

The above threw the following as the first compilation error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::tuple<std::vector<std::vector<int, 
std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >, 
std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, 
std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > > 
>::tuple(std::tuple<std::nullptr_t, std::nullptr_t>)’
 );
```

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. What does "compile-time recursion over a given set of template template classes" mean? Do you mean a variadic list of template template classes, and you want to iterate over them? How does a given template template class `compute a given function`? And the given code has fundamental flaws setting aside anything to do with templates. Declaring a `const std::tuple<Tp...>& types`, no matter what `Tp...` is, will be ill-formed. You cannot declare a reference to anything without initializing it. C++ does not work this way. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: still novice, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with initialization of the tuple, `nullptr` are not valid for `std::vector`.

You might use default initialization:

```
const std::tuple<int, double> type1{};
const std::tuple<std::vector<std::vector<int>>,
                 std::vector<std::vector<double>>> type2{};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85b5bd522c8d9b42)